# MVC DropDownListFor basic True False in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to setup a basic DropDownListFor in MVC:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, new SelectList(new SelectListItem { Text = "True", Value="1" } , new SelectListItem { Text = "False", Value="0"}))
```

This is in my view and what I'm wanting is a basic dropdown of `true` and `false` with values of `1` and `0` respectively.

I'm thinking the part I have wrong is adding the items to the SelectList constructor.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Because I'm in a strange mood... generally you want "Yes"/"No" on the UI instead of non user-friendly bool speak, but it depends on your app. Anyway, my problem is solved - thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.CheckerApproved, new [] { new SelectListItem { Text = "True", Value="1" } , new SelectListItem { Text = "False", Value="0"} })
```

Answer (score 3):

For something like this, why don't you simply just emit a Select tag with Options in your view ?

```
<select id='ddlTrueFalse' name='ddlTrueFalse'>
  <option value='1'>True</option>
  <option value='0'>False</option>
</select>
```

Then in your Action add the parameter:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string ddlTrueFalse)
{
  //ddlTrueFalse will be "1" or "0"
}
```

I've had to do a few of these, and I actually wrote this as an extension method to HtmlHelper, but its a lot cleaner, its easy to debug and it's faster for the site in general.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use an EditorTemplate that is designed for a Bool property...

Comment: I know it might seem disingenuous that you have to parse the string to a bool; but in reality that's all the MVC model binder is doing anyway, so you're not losing or gaining anything from hiding the cast.

Answer (score 2):

This already exists -- if you do `Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyBoolean)` you will get a drop down list with True/False and a default of Unset or similar.

Comment: Depends on the model: if `MyBoolean` is not nullable, you'll get a checkbox. Depending on what's required, this is potentially a better approach.

Comment: Good point -- so used to using nullable now I forgot that detail.

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time figuring out how to add a "class" to the code above, so I shared this, had to put original dropdown list in brackets, then add an overload

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.CheckerApproved, (new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "True", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "False", Value = "0" } }), new { @class = "form-control" } )


@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.CheckerApproved, (new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "Selected", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Not Selected", Value = "0" } }), new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

I add this as additional info, as it allows the designed to choose the name of the drop down option while allowing the programming team to still force a bool. Separation of form from design.

Comment: This works and you get to style it using CSS class, not sure why the downvote.